# IPN feedback for 2 people

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn

I have a page on my site which sends out payments to more than 1 person.  I've been testing this using the paypal sandbox account with a few test accounts.

I am also using ipn to get feedback from paypal when payments are complete, pending etc.

My question is, paypal sends me back info via ipn for just 1 of the payments.  Why is that?  When I check the payment amount in the ipn, it only shows me the payment for 1 of the people who got paid.  For example:

If I pay person 1 and 2, where each person gets paid $10 each, so a total of $20.  The ipn page only shows me the details for person 1 and says that the payment amount was $10, when the total payment amount is $20.

This is causing me a problem because I need to know that both payments were successful via ipn.  At the moment I can only check the payment for 1 person at a time, even though I am paying 2 people at the same time.

How do I get payment for both people?

Comment: can you post your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Pete  answer is a violation of the Paypal User Agreement (unless you have a separate legal entity for both accounts)

```
9. Restricted Activities
    9.1 Restricted Activities. In connection with your use of our website, your Account, or the Services, or in the course of your interactions with PayPal, a User or a third party, you will not:
        a. Breach this Agreement (including, without limitation, opening multiple PayPal accounts or breaching the Card Processing Agreement, the Acceptable Use Policy or any other agreement that you have entered into with PayPal (including a Policy));
```

What you are looking for is [PayPal Adaptive Payments](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/). A note about this though: one account - probably you as the application owner - must have a PayPal business account. The others that receive a payment only need a personal account.

PayPal provides an SDK with samples for the Adaptive Payments on [Github](http://paypal.github.io/). Select `Adaptive Payments` from the menu on the left. There are samples for multiple languages that should be able to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

My hunch is that IPN is tied to the individual account, not the payment, and you have the IPN set up from just one of the accounts. I think what you need to do is configure the IPN on both accounts and then process the response from PayPal two times... once from the IPN notification of the first account, and once from the IPN notification of the second account.